# Upgraded Laravel from 9 to 10 and phpunit 10, after that all test cases are failing

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

As the title implies: Recently, I did a Laravel upgrade from 9 to 10 and PHPUnit 10. After the upgrade, all test cases are failing.

> PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of
> Illuminate\Database\PDO\Concerns\ConnectsToDatabase::connect(array
> $params, $username = null, $password = null, array $driverOptions =
> []) must be compatible with Doctrine\DBAL\Driver::connect(array
> $params): Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Connection in
> /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/PDO/Concerns/ConnectsToDatabase.php
> on line 22

Tried to downgrade to the previous version, and all test cases are working as expected. Not sure if there are any deprecations in newer versions

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"type": "project",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": [
    "framework",
    "laravel"
],
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
    "php": "^8.2",
    "ext-gnupg": "*",
    "awobaz/compoships": "^2.0",
    "doctrine/dbal": "^3.0",
    "elasticsearch/elasticsearch": "^7.16",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "7.7",
    "kevinrob/guzzle-cache-middleware": "^4.1",
    "laminas/laminas-stdlib": "^3.3",
    "laravel/framework": "^10.0",
    "laravel/horizon": "^5.19",
    "laravel/sanctum": "^3.2",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.8",
    "launchdarkly/server-sdk": "^5.1",
    "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^3.15",
    "league/flysystem-sftp-v3": "^3.15",
    "mnapoli/dbal-schema": "^1.3",
    "ratchet/pawl": "^0.4.1",
    "staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep": "^1.18",
    "textalk/websocket": "^1.6"
},
"require-dev": {
    "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.5",
    "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
    "laravel/pint": "0.1.5",
    "laravel/telescope": "^4.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^6.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^10.0",
    "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^2.0",
    "orchestra/testbench-core":"^6.0"
},
"config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true
},
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": [
            "laravel/telescope"
        ]
    }
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
        "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
"scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
    ]
}
}
```

Comment: Maybe update doctrine/dbal? Yep, check here https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/upgrade#updating-dependencies

Comment: Did you follow the upgrade guide? Show us your `composer.json` if the previous comment is not working for you

Comment: Followed upgrade guide, not able to understand what is the issue. I feel this is something related to Doctrine\DBAL, sometimes I am getting error as  "Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDO\Exception: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near "(": syntax error" but same works with previous version

Comment: What version did you downgrade to? you need to be explicit on what you did and worked again

Comment: I reverted back to Laravel 9 and phpunit 9.3, basically reverted back to previous version. I would like to run my application with latest versions of Laravel and PHPUnit, but unable to continue as test cases are failing, tested couple of APIs and it is working. Is there any way I can automate all test cases to convert to new version compatibility.

Comment: I am not sure what to say... Using Laravel 10 and PHPUnit 10 is totally compatible

Comment: @Santosh Laravel Shift has [something](https://laravelshift.com/laravel-test-generator) to do that, but it's not free.